# How can I change the default mouse cursor position to center screen?

Tags: scripts, login, mouse, startup, default

I would like the login and startup default position of the mouse cursor to be the center of the screen.

Every time I log in and when Ubuntu 20.04 (64 bit) starts up, the mouse cursor's default position is the lower right hand corner of the screen. This is driving me crazy.

Do I need to make a startup script that runs with xdotool?

Please advise.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this using `xdotool`

1. Install `xdotool` which will be used to move the cursor. In a terminal use:

   ```
   sudo apt install xdotool
   ```
2. Create a .desktop file to be executed when you login.

   ```
   gedit ~/.config/autostart/move_cursor.desktop
   ```
3. Paste the following and you can change the `Exec` line to modify the coordinates to where the cursor will move, this is made to center the cursor in a `1920x1080` resolution screen.

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Center Cursor
   Comment=Move the cursor to the center of the screen.
   Type=Application
   Exec=xdotool mousemove 960 540
   X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
   ```
4. Save file and reboot to see changes.

This will take effect after the login page on your system, so when you get to the desktop you'll see the cursor in the center of the screen.

Comment: you can use xdotool getmouselocation to determine the top right location where you would manually click. not sure why it is not working. it appears to only work with coordinates within the terminal window. konsole in my case.